# How can I apply color to the line element upto specified offsetwidth using css style?

Tags: java, css, gwt, width, element

want to apply specified color  to the Line element upto specified widht?

Wherever I click on the line I am getting the offsetWidth of it, so I have to apply different color upto that offsetwidht, How can I do this, any idea?

```
int lineWidth = DOM.getElementPropertyInt(lineElement, "offsetWidth");
int lineLeftOffset = (width / 2) - (lineWidth / 2);
DOM.setStyleAttribute(lineElement, "left", lineLeftOffset + "px");
```

Here using lineLeftOffset I am setting current position, And till the current position I have to give different color to the lineElement.
   I tried following but it is applying color to whole element.

```
 DOM.setStyleAttribute(lineElement, "backgroundColor", "red");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with 2 elements - One your LineElement and other is just a div. Add this div as a child element to LineElement. Set your lineLeftOffset and background to the child div element like -

```
<div id="LineElement">
  <div></div>
</div>

#LineElement {
   background-color: black;
  padding: 3px;
}

#LineElement div {
   background-color: orange /* set the color from the java code */;
   width: 40%; /* Adjust the width from the java code */
   height: 2px;
}
```

For accessing the child div you can use

> lineElement.getElement().getFirstChild();

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be useful to use span element inside a div as an inline-block and then apply color to it.

```
<div id="LineElement"><span>&nbsp;</span></div>

CSS:

#lineElement{
    background-color:#000033;
    height:5px;
}
#lineElement > span{
    background-color:red;
    height:inherit;
    display:inline-block;
}
```